# Stop a HTML5 form posting, refreshing or opening a new window onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the HTML5 form tag for the client side validator built into it, but I don't want it to submit a thing as I've just got a Javascript function to run instead.

How can i stop the Post method of the form.

Cheers - Caius

Comment: Is jquery an option? or raw js?

Answer (score 5):

add a **return false** after the function call, like so:

```
<input .... onclick="function();return false;" />
```

or you could just return true/false from the function like so:

```
<input .... onclick="return function()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay that stops the submit process, but now the validation doesn't seem to work. any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, adding the code shouldn't stop your function from running at all. Check that the function is running (maybe add some debug code), and make sure the function is returning true/false if you're using the bottom example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can do:

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
  // do your staff
});
```

You can also do it without a framework:

```
document.getElementById('your_form_id').addEventListener('submit' function() {
  // do your staff
  return false;
});
```

In the "// do your staff" you can write your ajax code.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer leaving my functions as they are and add a return false to the onsubmit handler, ex:

```
<form onsubmit="aFunction(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the onsubmit property to your form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return myfunction()">
```

ensure you return a bool for your function

```
function myfunction() {
  // do your validation
  if (validation.passes)  { // you will need to change this line !!!
     return true; // to submit
  } else {
     return false; // to prevent submit
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a onsubmit handler to your form, e.g.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return sendForm();">
```

Then define the function and add false as return value:

```
function sendForm() {
    //do your ajax request...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've try all your solution but it still to reload the page after the ajax process :

```
<form id="form2" method="POST" onsubmit='sent(); return false;' >

function sent(){
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```