# Avoid refreshing the form in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in the same problem which has been raised here:

[Stop a HTML5 form posting, refreshing or opening a new window onSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756584/stop-a-html5-form-posting-refreshing-or-opening-a-new-window-onsubmit)

I currently use

```
event.preventDefault();
// to avoid refreshing of form
```

Sample code what i am trying is below :

my html page contains below snippet of code:

```
<form id="sampForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" required><br>
  Age: <input type="number"  required><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="OnSub(event)">
</form>
```

my js code below :

```
OnSub= function (_event) {
    try {
        _event.preventDefault();
   //do my process logic below or run any code here

    } catch (e) {

    }

};
```

> But this causes the form validations to stop working .

Thanks in advance for any help in here

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `value="OnSub(event)"` in your HTML-Code and i cannot see how you bind your function to your form.

Comment: updated the code its not value= its onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the form has an "onsubmit" event. Bind your function to that.

```
<form id="sampForm" onsubmit="OnSub(event)">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" required><br>
  Age: <input type="number"  required><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: its one and the same i have provided my button the type as an submit

Comment: it's not the same. you bind to the click on a button, but wanted to bind to the form submission. it is a difference not only en detail. someone could press the button with the keyboard or by touching it. both won't fire your "onclick".

Comment: +1 Thanks was in assumption they are one an the same . Thanks for reply and for helping out

Answer (score -1):

I feel you are using a method on form submit to validate elements
So In the end of your method just add

```
return false;
```

This will stop form submission.